# Reading a file from start to middle and end to middle possible?

Tags: algorithm

Is it possible to read a file from start to middle on one computer and read it from end to middle on another computer and then combine both the files to get the original file?
if so, how?

Comment: Yes, why not? When you have read the two halves, you somehow have to bring both to the same computer (either one of the two or a third one) and combine them. And how do the two computers have access to the same file in  the first place? Is it on a shared file system?

Comment: well it could be used to download the file faster. if the file is online, one half can be downloaded by one computer and the other half by another computer

Comment: "download" and "read" are two different things. You will not be able to download a file "from end to middle" without special software at the sending side. On the other hand downloading from middle to end is possible.